# @InjectMock(deepMock=true) deprecation fix, How to use it after removal?

Tags: java, junit, quarkus

I got a project that I am doing a Quarkus Update on. The project uses the DeepMock Option while doing JUnit Tests. Probleme is that this is marked for removal and making issues when trying to remove.

So far I haven't found any docs detailing how to replace DeepMock with oncoming JUnit and Mokito versions.
Does anyone have an Solution?

I tried to just remove to option, leading to a failure of all effected JUnit-Tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous `@InjectMock` annotation (`io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.InjectMock`) is deprecated for removal, because it may be used on places where its configuration options (`convertScopes`, `returnsDeepMocks`) don't make sense. The new `@InjectMock` annotation (`io.quarkus.test.InjectMock`) doesn't have the configuration options.

The replacement is the `@MockitoConfig` annotation (`io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.MockitoConfig`), which has the same configuration options. Use the new `@InjectMock` annotation together with `@MockitoConfig`.

Comment: how does the new Mockitoconfig handle convertscopes? I am new to JUnit Mockito and just trying to update legacy code.

Comment: It's the same as before. The annotation got split into two, there are no other changes.